# Facebook OAuth AccessToken Expiration

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I need help with Facebook OAuth. I am trying to make a facebook news feed gadget for my webpage. What I did is, I created a facebook login page, got the verification code, and then got the access token. There is an expiry parameter in the access token.

My question is, what happens when the token gets expired? Does it become a new token person logs in again. I want to store it in a database, so I can access it anytime I navigate through the webpage.

If I use the access token, will it still get expired? Or does it expire if its not been used for the given expiration time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your initial question, is that an access token is only valid whilst the user is logged in.  So yes, a new access_token will need to be retrieved every time they log in to your site.  This is detailed in the [authentication flow documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication2/).

In order to get an access token which is does not have an expiry (or has a long validity period), you will need to get the user to authorise the `offline_access`.  This should be set in your scope.

Here's a description of the `offline_access` permission from [this documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/):

> offline access - Enables your app to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.

This will not however, give you access forever.  If the user changes their password, or deauthorises your application, you will need to get the user to reauthorise it to get a new access_token.  If you try to use an out of date access token, an error message will be returned.  That's why it's important to have a flow which will allow for such eventualities.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge you can achieve this by asking for access my information anytime permission (offline_access) while a user does fconnect.

Answer (score 1):

For Detail information please refer

For Permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

For expired Token: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/